# Footer freezes after scrolling in iphone

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, iphone

I would like the footer to stay at the bottom right of the screen, but when I check the website on my iPhone, the footer stays up when I scroll down, it looks like this, http://imgur.com/Fgfjg54. Could someone please help? Thanks for your time, have a good day!

the website is pinzoniradian.com if seeing the website would help to find solution if you need to inspect, or if you could see if you get any errors on your devices or systems.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Lindsey</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="css/yourCustom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

</head> 
<body>
<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" style="color:#000000">Paulo Pinzon-Iradian</a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
        <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="work.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Work</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

      <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active">
            <img src="lindsey.jpg" style="width:370px;" alt="lindsey">
            <figcaption>Lindsey</figcaption>
            <figcaption>Damaged iPhone and Image</figcaption>
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="liferockslifesucks.html" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="malek.html" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
      </div>

  <footer class="footer">
      <div class="container" style="display: table; height: 50px; overflow: hidden;">
        <p class="text-muted" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">&copy; 2013-2015 Paulo Pinzon-Iradian, All Right Reserved</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

@font-face
{
    font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
    src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

.navbar-default{
    background: #fff;
    margin-top:2%;
    border:0px;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}

ul, li, a
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
    border:0px;
}


.container .jumbotron.no-padding
{
    background: #fff;
    border:0px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    color:#000000;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align: right;
}
.footer .container {
    width: 100%;
}

.right.carousel-control, .left.carousel-control {
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* IE support */
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

img
{
    margin:auto;
}

figcaption
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

setting footer `position` to be `absolute` needs a div with which it can reference itself, by default every div `position` is set `static` Simply use

```
body{
    position:relative;
}
```

This will make footer align itself relative to a HTML tag i.e., `body`